Rive events not reported when artboard loaded from file data
I'm loading my rive file like this
final riveAnimationData = await rootBundle.load(riveFilePath);
final file = RiveFile.import(riveAnimationData);

Then I create a StateMachineController like this:
final stateMachineController = StateMachineController.fromArtboard(
    artboard,
    'State Machine 1',
    },
  );

I then attach an event listener to the controller like this
stateMachineController.addEventListener((event) {
    print(' Normal Event${event.name}');
  });

And I display my rive animation like this
Rive(
  artboard: artboard
      .instance(),
  useArtboardSize: true,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  enablePointerEvents: true,
)

When I tap on the listener that reports my event it does nothing.
I also print out the events on the artboard just to make sure it's there and I get this output.
 Events  Artboard events: [Instance of 'Event' (47) -> next_tapped]

Does anyone know why events wouldn't fire if animations are loaded in this way instead of using RiveAnimation.asset?
